# Как достать уникальные элементы коллекции из двух листов

Tags: java, java-8

Есть две коллекции:

```
List<String> c1 = {"a", "b", "c"};
List<String> c2 = {"a", "g", "c"};
```

Как отсюда получить элементы, которые встречаются только 1 раз в двух колелкциях? ("b" и "g")

Comment: Используйте хеш таблицу

Answer (score 0):

Посмотрите в сторону removeAll для коллекций

```
List<String> c1 = {"a", "b", "c"};
List<String> c2 = {"a", "g", "c"};

ArrayList<String> add = new ArrayList<String>(c1);
add.removeAll(c2);
System.out.println("c1-c2: " + add);

ArrayList<String> remove = new ArrayList<String>(c2);
remove.removeAll(c1);
System.out.println("c2-c1: " + remove);
```

Comment: а если элемент будет повторяться, но только одной коллекци, а во второй такого элемента не будет совсем?

Comment: Вы, пожалуйста, четко сформулируйте вопрос, что вы хотите сделать.
Получить уникальные элементы коллекции можно так Set<String> unique = new HashSet<String>(c1);

Comment: я не автор вопроса, я просто привел вам контрпример вашего решения